# Method panelSelectionDidChange from NSOpenSavePanelDelegate protocol called twice

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I have a class that implements `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate` protocol and is associated with a NSOpenPanel.

I included a `NSLog()` in the `- (void)panelSelectionDidChange:(id)sender` method and noticed the following:

When I first select a file the `panelSelectionDidChange` is called, and checking `[sender URL]` I get the URL of the selected file, but when I select another file,  `panelSelectionDidChange` is called twice, the first time `[sender URL]` has the last URL and the second time it is called `[sender URL]` has the URL of the newly selected file.

But if I use the keyboard arrows to select the file instead of clicking on it `panelSelectionDidChange` is called only once with the correct URL.

Is this the normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me; you could file a report with Apple.  Generally the *way* the user makes a change should have no effect on how the change is perceived as long as the outcome is the same both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem also, I noticed that this only happens when the open panel is in browser mode, as opposed to list, icons, or preview (not sure those are the official names). The user can change this using the buttons on the upper left corner of the panel.

I believe the first call happens when you first select the item, and the second call happens when the preview is presented on the right side of the browser.

Not exactly a solution I know, but probably this information will help somehow.